# Completely remove Opacity in Toastr.js?

Tags: css, less, toastr

Is there a way to REMOVE completely the Transparency on Toastr.js?
I tried to change the various lines on the .less files

```
.opacity(@opacity) {
@opacityPercent: 100; // instead of @opacity * 100;
opacity: 1; // instead of @opacity;
-ms-filter:  ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
     }
```

and every place where it stated **opacity(x)** where x was not 1 but it still displays opacity.

I also tried to add the following lines on my own CSS

```
.toast {
   opacity: 1;
}

#toast-container > div {
   opacity: 1; 
}
```

but i still get the semi opacity on div message display. On mouse over, the div color becomes full (no transparency). I'm trying to always have it full color (no transparency).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try overriding it using !important:

```css
.toast {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#toast-container > div {
  opacity: 1 !important; 
}
```

You can also try "inspect element" in Chrome to see which css tag is causing the opacity.

If that doesn't work, can you perhaps provide a link to your page?

Comment: Important will work. But it also depends on where you put your CSS in relation to toastr's css. The sequence is important and should be considered before using !important.

Comment: Also, you should not edit the toastr.css but instead add your own custom css. Otherwise, when you upgrade toastr you will lose your changes to the toastr.css

Comment: It did work, but fadeIn and fadeOut stopped working.

Comment: The fadeIn / fadeOut most likely makes use of opacity - this of course disables that.

Comment: Please, please don't use `!important`.  It's very near never required and will almost always cause headaches for you or someone else in the future.

Answer (score 5):

### It Depends on What You Mean by "Remove"

If you don't want the mixin generating any CSS at all, but also don't want to remove all the mixin calls within the code, then just do this (comment out the code):

```
.opacity(@opacity) {
  // @opacityPercent: @opacity * 100;
  // opacity: @opacity;
  //-ms-filter:  ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
  //filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
}
```

The above will "do nothing." If you want some type of CSS generated (for some reason, I cannot think of why), but you do not actually want to have that code *apply* any `opacity` setting in the browser, then give it a bogus value that the browsers will ignore, something like this:

```
.opacity(@opacity) {
  @opacityPercent: bogus;
  opacity: bogus;
  -ms-filter:  ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacityPercent})";
}
```

You can check out that the above generates no opacity within a browser by looking [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMGE3/2/) and examining it with an inspection tool (like Firebug, etc.).

**I really believe you seek the first option however.**

Comment: Mainly I'm trying to have a full color with no transparency when I display a message. This currently only happens when I put the mouse over, but the initial message (the one that is fired by toast.warning("ddd") does appear semi transparent.

None of the suggested options work. It still semi transparent (:

Answer (score 3):

The following works with v2.1.3

```
#toast-container > div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

With the `!important` flag, there would be no fadeIn and fadeOut.

Comment: Using `!important` does break animation events even in the latest toastr, It shouldn't be recommended.